# Android communication sync keeps installing itself

Tags: ads, bloatware

My Android 4.4 based phone somehow gets 'Android communication sync' program which can be removed from downloaded apps.

This program shows fullscreen ads whenever I unlock phone.

My phone is rooted.

I install apps only from Play Market (few of them, only popular programs) and can not understand how it can be installed by itself (which app can do this).

I uninstall it and later (after week/month) in the morning it is installed again (it was not installed in the evening).